# Form is not saving

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Hello I have form and I can fill it but when I submit it nothing happens, I can add or edit the form in the admin panel but on the normal page as I said nothing happens. Can you please help me.

this is my template where you at the bottom see my form.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}



<div class="container">
    {% for i in distribution%}
    <div class='img1'>
        <img name="pic" src="{{ i.distribution.url }}">
        <p style="text-align:center;">{{i.lecture}} | {{i.semester}}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>


<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover results">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >Kullanıcı</th>
                <th >Yorum</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for j in commentmodel_list%}
        <tr>
            <th>{{j.author}}</th>
            <th>{{j.comment}}</th>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <button style="margin-bottom:10px;float:right;"type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Yorum Ekle</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Yorum</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form|crispy }}
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

this is my view

```
class LecturerDistribution(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Lecturer
    template_name = 'lecturer.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LecturerDistribution, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['distribution'] = Distribution.objects.filter(lecturer=self.object).order_by('lecture')
        context ['commentmodel_list'] = Comment.objects.filter(lecturer=self.object).order_by('created_on')
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'lecturer': self.object})
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author_security = self.request.user
        if form.instance.anon==True:
            pass
        else:
            form.instance.author=self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('distribution:lecturer_distribution', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

I think the problem is this, I want to have the Distribution and Comments listed in the page and want additionally a Comment Form. I am relatively new to django I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A [**`FormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) does not save the form, a [**`ModelFormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin) does. You thus can alter the mixin to `ModelFormMixin`, or you can save the form yourself:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class LecturerDistribution(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author_security = self.request.user
        if not form.instance.anon:
            form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    # …
```

But I would advice to use a `CreateView`, and simply pass the `Lecturer` object in the form (and `context`). Right now you focus on the `DetailView` to show the lecturer, and try to integrate a `ModelForm`, which is not how these mixins are designed to be used.

Comment: then I get the error that 'Lecturer' object has no attribute 'anon'

Comment: anon is a field of comment but why it is referring to lecturer

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü: well there is a mismatch by using it as `self.object`. If `self.object` exists, it is used as `instance` in the form as said before. This is one of the (many) reasons, why it is better to use a `CreateView`/`UpdateView`.

Comment: Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü: you can fix it by using a `FormMixin` and calling `form.save()`, but I would advice to turn this in a `CreateView`, where you pass the object in the `get_form_kwargs` and `get_context_data`. This will remove a lot of "patching".

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü: see edit to save the form with a `FormMixin`.